# Attachments in ActionMailbox/InboundEmails - unpermitted parametres

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to test how ActionMailbox works on localhost using:

http://localhost:5000/rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails

It works fine until I try to add an attachment. Then I receive an error:

```
ActionController::UnpermittedParameters (found unpermitted parameter: :attachments):

actionpack (6.1.3.1) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:973:in `unpermitted_parameters!'
actionpack (6.1.3.1) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:604:in `permit'
actionmailbox (6.1.3.1) app/controllers/rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails_controller.rb:23:in `new_mail'
actionmailbox (6.1.3.1) app/controllers/rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails_controller.rb:17:in `create'
```

I was trying to add :attachments to permitted parameters in line 23 of `inbound_emails_controller.rb` but with no effect :/

I have no idea why it doesn't work and nobody else found this bug :(

Comment: Provide `X_controller.rb` code to better understand HOW you permit parameters. And has_one :attachment or has_many :attachments?

Comment: it's rails code: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83217025a171593547d1268651b446d3533e2019/actionmailbox/app/controllers/rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails_controller.rb

Comment: Problem solved in rails: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/c6c53a02a5dfb99fba7c0886893fde46060fdcc7#diff-2040bc8a962e007d499a17050fc75518760a04fb0fcfded316fded7c3c73d7c4